# Reg expression to accept values between 1 and 48?

Tags: java, regex

I want a Reg expression to accept values within the range [1-48].

Comment: I want a billion of dollars

Comment: Regexes are for matching patterns, not comparing numeric values.

Comment: @RP89, since you are asking questions in SO, you might as well get used to its rules and regulations, some tacit, some explicit. You have to ask a good question, backed up by what you have tried till now, and what exactly do you want to achieve. Asking something like `I want to do this` will at best draw a stream of downvotes, but not a good answer, to the point where your question may even be deleted or locked. You are new, try to get used to it..

Answer (score 4):

You could try this regular expression: `^0*(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-8])$`

However, I'd advice using another mechanism for numeric validation if possible. Regular expressions are meant to match string patterns, as already pointed out in the comments.

Here's an explanation of the regex part by part:

- `^`: Beginning of string
- `0*`: Match any leading 0's
- `(?:` : Grouping the ORs (non-capturing group)

  - `[1-9]`: Match 1 to 9
- `|`: OR

  - `[1-3][0-9]`: Matches 10 to 39
- `|`: OR

  - `4[0-8]`: Matches 40 to 48
- `)` : Ends grouping the ORs
- `$`: End of string

See it working in [this RegExr](http://regexr.com?33lnh).

Some resources you might find useful to assist desiging/testing them yourself in the future:

- [Tutorial on regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)
- Online Regex testing tools: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) or [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not understood why you using regEx for this. You can directly say

```
if( x >= 1 && x <=48) {
   // x will fall in range[1-48] inclusive
}
```